# In codeigniter how to pass the array values to the same view page from controller?

Tags: codeigniter, view

I am new to codeigniter. with the help of jquery and ajax i am using multiple drop down list for selceting  cities and categories. for selecting cities i have already loaded the view page "index" and passed values from the controller as:

```
$this->load->view('index',$data);
```

but now for selecting categories, again i want to pass values and load the index view page.i have used as.

```
$this->load->view('index',$arrCategory);
```

$arrCategory is an array. now the problem is, *the index view page is loading within the same index view page.* But i can able to get the array values in view page.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$data = $other_datas;
$data['arrCategory'] = $arrCategory;

$this->load->view('index',$data);
```

Answer (score 2):

For more clarification

```
$data['otherData'] = $other_dropdown;
$data['arrCategory'] = $arrCategory;

$this->load->view('index',$data);
```